# Robocopy not copying drive folders with a complete copy command

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, robocopy

I'm trying to copy a hard drive with hundreds of folders at the root to another disk.

Here's my command currently:

```
robocopy H:\ I:\ /S /NFL /R:1 /W:60 /xd "H:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*" /LOG:"XXXX.txt"
```

All this does is put the files at the root of H: and place them on I:. It does not copy any of the folders.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for copying folder structures.   The first time may take awhile.   From then on it is more of an incremental backup.

```
XCOPY /Y /I /E /R D C:\ H:\backup
```

This doesn't make the destination drive bootable.  It does copy the files.